# Can a mage cast a sleep spell on themselves?

Tags: spells, adnd-2e

In AD&D v2, is it possible for a mage to cast the level 1 sleep spell on themselves and cause themselves to fall asleep?  Does the effect of the spell interfere with completing the casting of the spell somehow, thus prohibiting this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, if the mage casts *sleep* centred on herself, and there at no lower-HD creatures nearby which soak up the effect before it affects the mage, she will fall asleep.

The spell effect doesn't come into being until the spell is complete, so the *sleep* spell's effect certainly won't prevent itself from coming into effect.

Comment: Incidentally, the "the spell effect doesn't come into being until the spell is complete" thing is kinda demonstrated by the rules for interrupting spellcasting. Also, hypothetically speaking, if a wizard *were* able to interrupt his own sleep spell by falling asleep, and thereby prevent himself from casting the sleep spell, he wouldn't fall asleep, and so would complete the spell, and so would be able to create a time paradox at level one.