# Can a caster cast a sleep spell on themselves?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sleep

This question was asked for version 2E and the [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64324/can-a-mage-cast-a-sleep-spell-on-themselves) was yes. It's an interesting scenario as the caster is being attacked by multiple low hit point creatures. **Can the caster cast *sleep* on themselves?**

Comment: The concern, at least with your scenario and not the linked Q, is to make the creatures *around* the caster fall asleep, no? It might be useful to clarify if the intent is to center it on themselves, rather than affect themselves.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 66):

### No, but they can be affected by their own *Sleep* spell

They can't cast it on themselves because the target of the [Sleep](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sleep) is "a point you choose within range" and it affects creatures within 20 feet of that point. If the caster is within that area they can be affected by their own spell.

This applies to all area of effect spells, not just *Sleep*.

Comment: This answer is unhelpfully pedantic.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Pedantic, maybe, but this is RPG.SE. This is where pedantry lives. It also seems precisely correct: a caster cannot cast *Sleep* on themselves, because *Sleep* cannot target a creature (or self). But the caster can be put to sleep as a result of casting *Sleep*. What element of the question do you feel is not addressed by this answer?

Comment: +1 for both answering the question as written and what is probably the intended question.

Comment: The best pedantry is pedantry that answers the question as intended as well as adding useful correction to the question itself.  I think this fits the bill.

Comment: I will note that, in the first 5E session I ever played in, someone did exactly this. They cast sleep on a group of enemies that turned out to be zombies and thus immune. My character was also in the AoE, but he was a half-elf and thus was also immune. The only character in range and not immune was the caster.

Comment: @Upper_Case given we have both language and technical sites, I think it’s an exaggeration to say ‘this is where pedantry lives’.

Comment: In other words, no, they can't technically target _themselves_, but they could target a point a centimeter in front of their nose, which is almost the same. Or even a point inside their body, unless there's an implicit requirement for LOS?

Comment: @ilkkachu No, it's not almost the same. Sleep affects creatures in the AoE in order of their current hit points, so it depends on the other creatures (and their current hit points) within the AoE whether the caster is in fact affected or not.

Comment: @ilkkachu There generally is a requirement for LOS for almost all spells in 5e unless the spell explicitly says otherwise. This is actually kind of important, because a lot of spells become significantly more powerful without it (especially _Create Water_, which turns into a near guaranteed kill on a very large percentage of living things an adventuring party may encounter, either via forced drowning or via rupturing the target’s stomach/intestines).

Comment: @ilkkachu Mars Plactic's point is very important. Because the caster cannot guarantee that they will fall asleep. If there are entities hidden, but within range (lets say a big mole colony directly underground or in the bushes near you), and you roll the sleep-hp die badly, it could be that, even though you are pretty much at the center of the spell, you don't fall asleep. And that's the difference to casting it *on yourself*, because then you could be sure it'd hit you

Comment: @MarsPlastic, my point was that there doesn't seem to be much difference if it's centered on the caster or if it's centered on a point that happens to be where the caster is (or near enough that it doesn't matter). Even though it's technically different. The question mentions "being attacked by lots of low-HP creatures", so presumably the idea there is to use the area effect on others, not to force themselves to sleep.

Comment: @Fivesideddice That's not what I've observed in my time here-- answers which depart from rules are often poorly received. This is the first, and only, instance I've ever seen here of an answer being derided by an experienced and active user as being too aware and observant of the relevant rules, too correct in its description, and too direct of an answer to a question. And I'm *still* not clear on the complaint; the answer is clear and complete.

Comment: @Upper_Case The issue is not the *completeness* of the answer, the issue is the *implied snark* that is written into the answer.

Comment: @RevenantBacon I guess I just don't see any snark in the answer, though obviously what I happen to see isn't definitive. As I read it, the answer lays out the specific, relevant terms in the course of describing the way that casting *Sleep* operates in the game and resolves the question completely with no frills or commentary.

Comment: -1 A fully pedantic recognition would be that the OP did not ask if the caster can *target* themselves with the spell, but whether they can cast it *on* themselves. Those are two different phrases, and the latter is not a defined game term. Therefore a more generous interpretation is justified, and the answer should say "Yes" as its opening for maximal clarity (followed by further pedantic distinctions as desired). They can in fact cast it *on* their particular position in space, and it can affect them.

Comment: I think this answer missed the actual intent of the question; the intent isn't to affect themselves with *sleep*, but affect creatures *around the caster*. While this answer may contain the information which should resolve that concern, it seems to only do that accidentally.

Comment: @Someone_Evil  I don't think the intent of OP's question is clear.  Given that they linked to a question that asks if is "possible for a mage to cast the level 1 sleep spell on themselves and cause themselves to fall asleep", I don't think it is clear that, as you say, "the intent isn't to affect themselves with sleep".  It _might be_, but it is hardly clear.

Comment: @Kirt Yes, I have requested clarification on the actual question. I do however think answers would be better handling the situation described in the question and not the one in the related questions the querent had found and linked to :)

Comment: This is pedantically incorrect.  In 5e, the targets of a spell aren't those named "target" in the description.  The target(s) of a sleep spell **include the creatures in the area you pick**.  This is a 3e style interpretation of a 5e question.  The spell targets that spot, and all of the creatures within the area of effect.  Splitting "target" from "affect" is a difference that is in error.  The fact you can target yourself is true; the pedantic details should be corrected or removed to improve this answer.

Answer (score 18):

## It's risky, but it just might work.

The *sleep* spell affects all creatures within an area of your choice. Nothing precludes you from including yourself in that area.

If your aim is to neutralize the creatures around you, and they each have fewer hit points than you, then this isn't a bad tactic; you'll only be affected after *all* of them are affected, and since the spell doesn't require concentration, you'll all stay asleep no matter what happens to you.

Comment: On the other hand, it can be a great cure for insomnia.

Comment: @PJRZ unless you have a lot of HP, in which case your neighbours, roommates and pet spider will probably doze off, but you won't.

Answer (score -1):

### If you mean targeting a point within yourself, no

As mentioned in the comments on [Dale M's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/180805/28388), spells in D&D5e require Line of Sight unless they specifically state they don't. So, unless the caster's belly is transparent or an artificial wiregrid (think e.g. Tezzeret from MtG) or something like that, they can't cast Sleep within their stomach, for example.

#### An exception to this

are, as mentioned, body parts that are transparent in one form or another. A particularly intersting example, mentioned by Joshua in the comments, are the insides of your eyeballs, since they're transparent (and therefore viable) for any given self.

#### That said...

While you can't cast Sleep *within* your navel, nothing prevents you from casting it *in front* of your navel, at the very surface of your clothes and armor. As others mentioned however, you do run the risk of affecting yourself.

Comment: As I can see the blood cells crossing my own retina, I sure can pick a point within myself.

Comment: @Joshua True that; I guess the inside of the eyeballs falls under "transparent body parts" though.

Comment: Can I maybe get reasons for the downvotes? It's annoying not to know what I should improve.

Comment: Wasn't me, but "within their stomach" seems to be referencing question text that doesn't exist.

Comment: OK thanks, clarified that a little.